# Onsen-ui dynamic carousel

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm trying to dynamically update a carousel when you get near the bottom.

It's working but when the data is updated to add more rows (after the initial set) the carousel gets screwed up (wrong indexes, wont jump correctly).

I'm certain this can be better, bit new to angular so forgive me, any help would be appreciated.

js:

```
(function() {
    var rows=0;
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['onsen']);

    function addrows($scope, $http){
        $http.get('/data').success(function(data) {
            angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                angular.element(document.getElementById('updatediv')).append("<ons-carousel-item></ons-carousel-item>");
                rows++;
            });
            myCarousel.refresh();
        });
    }

    app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        addrows($scope, $http);

        setTimeout(function(){
            myCarousel.on('postchange', function(){
                if(myCarousel.getActiveCarouselItemIndex() == rows-2){
                addrows($scope, $http);
                }
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
})();
```

html

```
<ons-carousel var="myCarousel" id="updatediv"  style="width: 100%; height: 100%" direction="vertical" fullscreen="true" auto-scroll="true"></ons-carousel>
```

Comment: Did you get it to work ?